# AWS EC2 instance doesn't response using HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have AWS EC2 instance that sends the response using HTTP. The URL link is as below:

```
http://ec2-18-233-225-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3030/api/status
```

This works fine with the. S3 bucket after the deployment, but, the Cloudfront blocks request that are not comes using HTTPS. How do I make sure that HTTPS also work with this URL:

```
https://ec2-18-233-225-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3030/api/status
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cloudfront https handling:
Create certificate in ACM. Update cloudfront distribution to use that certificate and set ssl/TLS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-procedures.html#cnames-and-https-updating-cloudfront

for EC2 https handling: You need to open HTTPS port (443). To do that, you go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/ and click on the Security Groups link on the left, then create a new security group with also HTTPS available. Then, just update the security group of the instance.

After these steps, if it's still not working it is an application problem.

Comment: Does this mean "Create certificate in ACM" is not needed for "EC2 https handling"?

Comment: It's not needed if you handle SSL in EC2 - You can terminate SSL in your EC2. So you can manage the SSL certificates yourself.

Comment: Thx. i added 443 to ec2 and even allowed to `all` in one rule but still cant connect to ec2 through `https`. maybe i should open a new question post.

Answer (score 3):

`ec2-18-233-225-132.compute-1.amazonaws.com` domain belongs to AWS, not you. This means that you **can't have valid SSL certificate** for it. You must have **your own domain** if you want to enforce https between CF and EC2.

Once you get your domain, you can use https://letsencrypt.org/ to get valid free SSL cert for it. Alternatively, you can front your instance with a load balancer, and get free SSL cert for your domain using AWS ACM. Then you associate the SSL cert with the LB.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the Security Group of that Instance...
At left side ,down below the EC2 dashboard ; you can see Network and Security-- then click on Security Group.Click on it ...Then edit inbound Rules...Add https ,port 443

Comment: I did that but it doesn't work even after I open the port.